# Can't open /usr/share/debconf/confmodule - When install using apt-get

Tags: linux, debian, apt, debian-squeeze

I tried installing valgrind using,

```
apt-get install valgrind
```

After downloading the packages, am getting the following error,

```
Setting up tzdata (2013d-0squeeze1) ...
.: 9: Can't open /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
dpkg: error processing tzdata (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
configured to not write apport reports
                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 tzdata
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me in resolving these issues.

Am on Debian-Squeeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/usr/share/debconf/confmodule is a script that's part of debconf, a required package.  Check that it's present and readable:

```
# ll /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2690 Mar 15  2012 /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
```

If it's not readable, make it readable by `chmod a+r /usr/share/debconf/confmodule`.

If it's missing or damaged, try reinstalling debconf, `apt-get --reinstall install debconf`.